# Doubts About Use of Practical Closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to find out more about closures in Javascript and was going through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Practical_closures

According to this article, by using such a function:

```
function makeSizer(size) {  
    return function() {  
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  
    };  
}  

var size12 = makeSizer(12);  
var size14 = makeSizer(14);  
var size16 = makeSizer(16);
```

We can then make use of such statements to increase/decrease the font-size of text on a page:

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;  
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14; 
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
```

While I understand the concept here - i.e. size12, size14 and size16 become closures that allow access to the internal function, I can't help but feel that this is unnecessary. Isn't it easier to just have:

```
function makeSizer(size) {  
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  
}
```

, and then invoke it with these?

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = makeSizer(12);  
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = makeSizer(14); 
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = makeSizer(16);
```

Can anyone tell me if my thinking is right - or maybe I'm just a novice to Javascript and doesn't understand the advantage to using closure in this scenario, in which case I'll be most glad if you can explain the advantage of doing so.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: @Joseph: Na, that's a perfectly valid usage of closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you presented, of course closure is not necessary, but I guess it is just to make it simple to present the concept. There are cases though that closure is the best solution to use: think about how to implement a "private" attribute in javascript or when you need [curryng](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to encapsulate arguments (ie, for a callback function).

I hope the following example helps:

```
var makeSequencer = function() {
    var _count = 0; // not accessible outside this function
    var sequencer = function () {
        return _count++;
    }
    return sequencer;
}

var fnext = makeSequencer();
var v0 = fnext();     // v0 = 0;
var v1 = fnext();     // v1 = 1;
var vz = fnext._count // vz = undefined
```

Comment: a closure is perfectly sensible and valid use here because it _binds the supplied parameter_, although the same function to be used with different values.

Comment: Ok I think I know what you mean: so _count is a private variable that is only accessible by the sequencer function (as seen in `var v0 = fnext();` ). Do you think it's advisable to use `var v0=makeSequencer()();`, thereby skipping fnext?

Comment: @anthonyteo: it doesn't make sense; you can think  the `makeSequencer` function as a _factory_ that creates and return a new function (the sequencer itself) each time it is called.

Comment: Maybe closure is still too advanced for a javascript novice like me? I can't seem to understand why we would have a function return a function, then set a separate variable as this returned function, and use this separate variable to invoke this returned function. Seems like an awful amount of work to me. Although I do kinda understand the rationale behind this section on private methods: http://mzl.la/InJNwT

Comment: Closure sometimes is taken as a complicated concept, but I imo it's just another concept and it can be very useful. Don't give up little grasshopper :)

Comment: Haha thanks for the encouragement. Yeah ain't gonna give up just like that. I'm like 70-80% clear about it now, but I'm sure if I persist I'll soon understand it completely. Thanks a lot for all the help, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that.

It's as if you had written:

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = (function(size) {  
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  
})(12);
```

The function gets *immediately invoked*, the style will be applied straight away, and no `.onclick` handler gets registered because the return value of the function is `undefined`.

The real point of the example is to show that you can *return a function* from another function, and that you can then assign that result to an event handler.

---

If you had left `makeSizer()` unmodified then you could assign the handlers as proposed without intermediate variables, i.e.:

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = makeSizer(12);
```

but that **won't** work if you change `makeSizer()` the way you described.

It is also less efficient than storing the "sizer" in a variable if you use the same sizer more than once.

Comment: Hi @Alnitak, thanks for the clear explanation. I get what you mean now. One thing I don't get though - why is storing the 'sizer' in variables is more efficient than invoking the makeSizer function each time you need it? In the latter case, you're using a function already defined, while in the former you have to declare new variables, then invoke the function. Using variables seems more of a hassle to me, at least.

Comment: @anthonyteo because each time you call `makeSizer(n)` you're actually returning a new (function) object.

Comment: So I gather a new function object costs more than a new variable in terms of efficiency, right?

Comment: @anthonyteo each function requires a "scope" to be created, and is also an object in its own right.  Variables are _mostly_ just something used by the parser - once the code is parsed they're essentially free but object creation has a _run time_ penalty.

Comment: I don't actually understand everything you said above, but I'll definitely come back to your comment again later, when I'm more familiar with JS. Thanks a lot for your help in any case. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those variables (`sizeN`) are unnecessary. You can directly assign the result of `makeSizer()` as handlers, which looks far better.

But, the use of these variables is not the concept of closures. The closure in this example is the function `makeSizer`, which returns a *function* (even without arguments), which still has access to the `size` variable.

Though, you need to see the difference between

```
function makeSizer(size) {  
    return function resize() {  
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  
    };  
}
```

and

```
function resize(size) {  
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  
}
```

Executing `makeSizer(5)` does not do anything, it returns a function that sets the size to the pre-defined size when invoked. Instead executing `resize(5)` does set the size directly. You can't use the result of the latter function as an event handler.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, thanks for the explanation. Alnitak also mentioned handlers - sadly, I'm rather fuzzy over the concept of handlers, so I'm not sure what you guys mean. In particular, why would you need to register an `onclick` handler when what you really want is just to size the text accordingly?

Comment: You may want to read this [introduction into JS events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). If you want to size text directly (now, at runtime), execute the function. But if you want that to happen when the user clicks on an element, you will need to make the function execute when that event occurs.

Comment: Ah - I think I get what you mean. It's like waiting for the user to act before responding to it.