# Why is the practical closure example in Javascript on Mozilla advantageous?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, closures, mozilla

I am reviewing closures in Javascript on Mozilla and they give a practical example.  Can someone please explain why the Mozilla way using closures is superior to solving the problem without using closures shown below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Practical_closures

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
<a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
<a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>
```

Javascript

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}

var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
```

Why is that example superior to this?

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}

function size12() { makeSizer(12) }
function size14() { makeSizer(14) }
function size16() { makeSizer(16) }

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
```

I made a codepen with the two examples.
https://codepen.io/MicFin/pen/mAOBNa

Comment: In the end it doesn't really matter, it's just how you want to organize your code. In the first example you have a function that creates functions for you, in the second example you are creating the functions manually. You could ask the same question about constructor functions vs directly creating objects. If you have to generate the same/a similar thing over and over again, something like a "builder" function can be useful.

Comment: There's no significant advantage in this because you don't need state. In this case it's just a fancy way of doing it. The advantage comes from when you need to maintain state. For example you need several functions that return incremental values (or a more concrete example, you want to make several parallel AJAX requests). You can implement such a thing in OO as object or you can implement it in FP as closures.

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [Doubts About Use of Practical Closure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10348255/1048572)

Comment: It all comes down to [not repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). In this example it's minimal, a few function declarations could be spared, but the effect can be greater when e.g. used in a loop. Just read down that MDN page.