# Using Javascript Varibles Without Calling Functions In Them

Tags: javascript

I am currently devolving a little slideshow, thing that automatically moves fades in and out the background-images. (opacity as well.)
My issue is that I am trying to use variables to store code to run, as setTimeout is stubborn, and won't run with anything in parentheses in it. (as well I need to use them, or my code will get really messy..ier)
What I currently have is

```js
imgID = 0;
// window.setInterval(nextSLIDE, 1000);
nextSLIDE();

function nextSLIDE( step2 ) {
 slideVAR = "slide" + imgID;
    window.setTimeout(imgIDchange(), 50);
    test2 = window.setTimeout(changeOpacityNINE);
    tes5t = window.setTimeout(changeOpacity8, 100); // If you are wondering about the irradical names, that is because I made them all non-unique earlier, and I got lazy, so I made them unique..
    test4 = window.setTimeout(changeOpacity7, 200);
    test6 = window.setTimeout(changeOpacity6, 300); 
    tes6t = window.setTimeout(changeOpacity5, 400); 
    twest = window.setTimeout(changeOpacity4, 500); 
    testt = window.setTimeout(changeOpacity3, 600);
    testyt = window.setTimeout(changeOpacity2, 700);
    teswt = window.setTimeout(changeOpacity1, 800);

}
function imgIDchange() {
 imgID = imgID + 1;
}


function changeOpacity( opacity ) {
 document.getElementById("headerIMG").style.opacity = opacity;
}


var changeOpacityNINE = changeOpacity(0.9);
var changeOpacity8 = changeOpacity(0.8);
var changeOpacity7 = changeOpacity(0.7);
var changeOpacity6 = changeOpacity(0.6);
var changeOpacity5 = changeOpacity(0.5);
var changeOpacity4 = changeOpacity(0.4);
var changeOpacity3 = changeOpacity(0.3);
var changeOpacity2 = changeOpacity(0.2);
var changeOpacity1 = "changeOpacity(0.1);"
var FULL = changeOpacity(1)
```

And I am looking for a way to make it either

A) Work, and not run the varibles.
B) Or find some sort of other Work around..

If my design is *that* horrific, and makes your eyes bleed feel free to tell me how I can redo it, but I would rather not redo it all in general. (I am rather lazy..)

Comment: So what you're really asking is how to call a function with `setTimeout` **and** pass arguments to that function, right?

Comment: You're looking for closures. Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10348255/1048572)

Comment: If you are rather lazy in general, you should redo your code and use a loop instead of repeating everything :-)

Comment: Definately outsource the transition in opacity, instead of repeating the code 100 times.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why you're using javascript for this.. You can transition the background image with pure CSS, you know that right?

Comment: `window.setTimeout(imgIDchange(), 50);` executes the function immediately. You may want to learn about what a [function reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272/5743988) is.

Comment: @mhodges JS isn't exclusive to browser with CSS 3.

Comment: Oh yeah, I completely forgot about that... Well, that was 40 minutes wasted..

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) with a function and pass arguments to it?

If so, you can simply add the arguments to the end of your `setTimeout` call. So if you wanted to call

```js
changeOpacity(0.5);
```

after 1000 ms, then you would use `setTimeout` like this:

```js
setTimeout(changeOpacity, 1000, 0.5);
```

Comment: For some reason passing arguments to the `setTimeout` callback as a third argument is not very reliable. I've seen it not working time to time but just couldn't figure out why. It might be safer to do like `setTimeout(changeOpacity.bind(this,0.5), 1000);`

Comment: @Tobiq Pretty much [all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Browser_compatibility) (with the exception of IE9 and below, which is [less than 1%](http://caniuse.com/usage-table) of browsers) support extra arguments to `setTimeout`.

Comment: `I think *some* browsers only accept 1 argument – Tobiq`

Answer (score 3):

With setTimeout, the arguments are as follows:

```
setTimeout(callback,delay,args);
```

so you can simply do:

```
setTimeout(changeOpacity,*DELAY*,0.7); // etc...
```